# mostrar solo un numero de registros desde mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, tablas

Tengo la siguiente tabla en la cual se me muestra todo lo que se tiene que embarcar en los proximos dias, mediante un check box se selecciona lo que ira a cierta rampa en especifico no tengo ningun problema al asignar la informacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo que no se de que manera mostrar los 5 mas recientes tengo la siguiente consulta, pero como comento si muestra los mas recientes en un lapso de 1 hora pero son 7 registros los que muestra.

Consulta select para la tabla

```
$co = "SELECT * FROM plan_embarque WHERE rampa = 'RAMPA #1' AND Fecha_asi > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY Fecha_Reg ASC";
```

La tabla tiene el siguiente aspecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuacion les agrego un gif describiendo el proceso en mi tabla y ya tengo 7 envios asignados a la rampa 1, de los cuales solo se me muestra el destino y el serial en mi tabla  pero me muestra los 7 registros cuando yo solo requiero que me muestre 5 por que mediante el boton azul desplegare un modal con una tabla y en esa tabla tendre todos los envios que se asignaron a esa rampa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias

Comment: Déjame ver si te entendí. Primero que nada, en tu primera vista, puedes seleccionar (con un checkbox) registro por registro. Una vez que has terminado de seleccionar los registros que quieres, recuperas los ids o los registros que el usuario seleccionó. El problema que estás teniendo es, ¿cómo poder mostrar los registros que el usuario seleccionó ordenados por la fecha más reciente a las más antigua? Confírmame.

Comment: Mira en la primera vista yo a los registros les asigno una rampa mediante un update el checkbox solo me ayuda para hacer multiples update y no tener que hacerlo uno por uno

Comment: En la 2da vista me debe mostrar solo los registros que pertenecen a la rampa 1 pero a primera vista en la tabla solo requiero los 5 mas recientes en un lapso de una hora esto debido a que puede llegar a haber mas de 15 registros en esa hora pero yo solo requiero los 5 mas recientes ya que los demas los mostrare dentro de una tabla mostrada en un modal

Comment: @FernandoTorres añadi un gif ojala asi sea mas claro

Comment: no es claro por que no sabemos que codigo php, ajax etc se encarga de buscar la informacion etc ...

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces, la consulta que tienes te regresa 7 registros y quieres que esa misma consulta de regrese solo 5, puedes utilizar LIMIT para limitar el número de filas que necesitas mostrar:

```
SELECT * FROM plan_embarque WHERE rampa = 'RAMPA #1' AND Fecha_asi > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY Fecha_Reg ASC LIMIT 5
```

pd: lo puse como respuesta porque no puedo comentar

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio muy bien